# Negatively updating a Python dict [NOT "key"]

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looking for a way to update/access a Python dictionary by addressing all keys that do NOT match the key given.

That is, instead of the usual `dict[key]`, I want to do something like `dict[!key]`. I found a workaround, but figured there must be a better way which I cannot figure out at the moment.

```
# I have a dictionary of counts
dicti = {"male": 1, "female": 200, "other": 0}

# Problem: I encounter a record (cannot reproduce here) that 
# requires me to add 1 to every key in dicti that is NOT "male", 
# i.e. dicti["female"], and  dicti["other"], 
# and other keys I might add later

# Here is what I am doing and I don't like it
dicti.update({k: v + 1 for k,v in dicti.items() if k != "male"})
```

Comment: That's about as simple as you'll get it. There can only be one matching key, so it's quick and easy to look it up, but there is an arbitrary number of non-matching keys.

Comment: What specifically is worrying you? Performance / syntax / something else?

Comment: If you have to do this _a lot_, then a much more efficient way would be to have a separate variable `n`, and then do `dicti["male"] -= 1; n+= 1` and in the end (after several updates in this form) add`n` to all the values.

Comment: @jpp mainly that I feel it looked overly complicated/hacky & I was wondering about the performance as well, as explained in the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to perform this "add to others" operation more often, and if all the values are numeric, you could also *subtract* from the given key and add the same value to some global variable counting towards *all* the values (including that same key). For example, as a wrapper class:

```
import collections
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, **values):
        self.d = collections.Counter(values)
        self.n = 0
    def add(self, key, value):
        self.d[key] += value
    def add_others(self, key, value):
        self.d[key] -= value
        self.n += value
    def get(self, key):
        return self.d[key] + self.n
    def to_dict(self):
        if self.n != 0:  # recompute dict and reset global offset
            self.d = {k: v + self.n for k, v in self.d.items()}
            self.n = 0
        return self.d
```

Example:

```
>>> dicti = Wrapper(**{"male": 1, "female": 200, "other": 0})
>>> dicti.add("male", 2)
>>> dicti.add_others("male", 5)
>>> dicti.get("male")
3
>>> dicti.to_dict()
{'other': 5, 'female': 205, 'male': 3}
```

The advantage is that both the `add` and the `add_others` operation are O(1) and only when you actually need them, you update the values with the global offset. Of course, the `to_dict` operation still is O(n), but the updated dict can be saved and only recomputed when `add_other` has been called again in between.

Comment: you had the same idea as me: add for all then make up for the special one. Also good use of `Counter`. One has to adapt to OP special case (dict of integers).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ah, I did not see your edit, but my comment was still earlier. ;-) Also, it seems like you still update all the values, so still O(n), just without the `if` check.

Comment: without wrapping, you have no choice. Your `to_dict` is also `O(n)`. But if you have to increase more than once, your solution is superior (sorry, can't upvote more than once)

Answer (score 5):

```
dicti.update({k: v + 1 for k,v in dicti.items() if k != "male"})
```

that creates a sub-dictionary (hashing, memory overhead) then passes it to the old dictionary: more hashing/ref copy.

Why not a good old loop on the keys (since the values aren't mutable):

```
for k in dicti:
   if k != "male":
       dicti[k] += 1
```

Maybe faster if there are a lot of keys and only one key to avoid: add to all the keys, and cancel the operation on the one key you want to avoid (saves a lot of string comparing):

```
for k in dicti:
   dicti[k] += 1
dicti["male"] -= 1
```

if the values were mutable (ex: lists) we would avoid one hashing and mutate the value instead:

```
for k,v in dicti.items():
   if k != "male":
       v.append("something")
```

One-liners are cool, but sometimes it's better to avoid them (performance & readability in that case)

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot sense! I mainly objected to the loop as "too many lines for this simple operation" , which is silly.